# How to bake all animation from ik to fk in blender2.66

Tags: animation, constraints, baking

I need to export animation to my game which doesn't support ik.
So i need to bake ik to fk before export.
I can bake one animation via bake action (with clear constraint toggle on because there is no visual keyframe option in 2.66)
, but this will delete the constraints,then i have to recreate these constraints to bake other actions .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should toggle clear_constraint off

Comment: i have to toggle it on, there has no visual key option in blender2.66

Comment: if i toggle clear_constraint off, only ik target bone has animation

Comment: how many actions do you have ? (maybe copy the object and bake each one)

Comment: 13 actions,  this might be a solution

Answer (score 1):

I made a Blender Addon that does exactly this.

It generates a new mesh and FK rig, so that your original one remains completely unchanged.

So you can simply export the rig that the Addon generates and then delete it. When you need to export again, just use it to regenerate a new FK rig.

It's open source on GitHub - https://github.com/chinedufn/blender-iks-to-fks

Hope it helps!